# Client side React.JS frontend - is this react code only for server side

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

This is a certainly a beginner's question, but I am confused and haven't been able to google my way out of it/find a decent article.

I'm fairly new to web dev, and I've built a small ASP.NET MVC application. I now want to make my frontend (view) attractive and fluid, and I want to use React to do this.

So I 'install' react in a html document by including the following scripts in the head:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0-alpha1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
```

I went looking for an existing implementation of a popup tooltip and came across: `https://github.com/romainberger/react-portal-tooltip/tree/master/example` I like the 'groups' tooltips.

However, I'm stuck on how to install this. I *think* this is the only file I need from the repro:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/romainberger/react-portal-tooltip/master/src/index.js

correct?

So I simply include this from 
`
import React from 'react'
import ToolTip from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/romainberger/react-portal-tooltip/master/src/index.js'
import {NicolasCage} from 'react-image-placeholder'

export default class Style extends React.Component {
  state = {
    display: false
  }
  getText() {
    let base = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`

```
let text = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  text.push(base)
}

return text
```

}
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({display: true}), 0)
  }
  escape(html) {
    return document.createElement('div').appendChild(document.createTextNode(html)).parentNode.innerHTML
  }
  getBasicExample() {
    return {
      __html: this.escape(`let style = {
  style: {
    background: 'rgba(0,0,0,.8)',
    padding: 20,
    boxShadow: '5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5)'
  },
  arrowStyle: {
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.8)',
    borderColor: false
  }
}
<ToolTip parent="#style-btn" active={true} position="bottom" arrow="center" style={style}>
  <NicolasCage/>
</ToolTip>`)
    }
  }
  render() {
    let style = {
      style: {
        background: 'rgba(0,0,0,.8)',
        padding: 20,
        boxShadow: '5px 5px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5)'
      },
      arrowStyle: {
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.8)',
        borderColor: false
      }
    }

```
return (
  <div style={{padding: 20}}>
    <div style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
      <p>You can provide a <code>style</code> prop to customize some part of the tooltip. You can give it
```

an object with two properties: `style`, that will be applied to the tooltip itself, and

`arrowStyle` which will be applied to the arrows. The last one is tricky as the arrows are made

with borders so it can be painfull to customize. To make it easier, the `arrowStyle.color` property

will change the background color of the arrow and `arrowStyle.borderColor` its border. To remove

completely the border use a falsy value.

tooltip/blob/master/example/src/style.js">Check out this example to see how this one is done

Thanks react-image-

placeholder!

{style}>
            
          
        
        {this.getText()}
      
    )
  }
}

But I cant see any effect, and think I'm probably taken multiple wrong turns at this point.

I'm confused as all the pages file in the Github repo are .js and the example html files don't reference them. The only thing I see them referencing is  bundle.js, which my gut tells me is some concatenation of all JS scripts used to speed things up (probably prevent roundtrip/latency in request JS files individually). Nowhere do I see directly embedded JS into html files.

Note, I haven't installed node, I'm just adding this code to my view code - html pages (actually cshtml pages). My limited understanding is that I only require node if I want to do server side JS development.

I'm very new to this. I expect I've muddled plenty of concepts, but I would like to get to the part where I know how to correctly 'install' third party React components and begin writing my own React.

Thanks

Comment: Node is commonly used in front-end development to run tasks like concatenating, minifying, and through tools like webpack or browserify, import modules and spit out bundles. Node is also used for NPM to download client side packages (like React etc). If I were you, I would install node, pull down a react boilerplate repo like this one https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate and get used to the whole modules in JavaScript thing. Once you're comfortable you can go back to your .NET stuff and make more sense of it. You may decide that you don't need .NET at all for your front end.

Comment: Thanks azium. I think I might just do that. A question, are you familar with .NET? How would one remove a '.NET front end' in an ASP.NET application. The razor engine (think .cshtml), allows for passing of data from your Controllers's ActionResult to your front end. I'm not sure how I'd get data from my controller into my view. My gut tells me, that if I wanted to use JS entirely for my frontend I wouldn't want an ASP.NET MVC application, rather a .NET web service which spits out data (e.g. JSON) to and from the front end. Is this what you (primarily) mean by not having .NET as my front end?

Comment: Precisely. When your Front end app boots up it makes an ajax request to get any initial data it needs to display. Essentially you would have separate front end and back end applications that know how to communicate via JSON. It's a fantastic architecture, the perfect way to separate concerns.

Comment: Have you yourself done this with a .NET stack? Did you use ASP.NET API or MVC. Have you tried with ASP.NET/ASP.NET core/MVC 6? Can you point me to any good material on accomplishing this?

Comment: I have done this before in a variety of stacks, but it's always the same type of thing, backend has routes that accept / serve json, do database things.. and the front receives / sends and paints dom nodes somehow. This looks decent for the back end http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/creating-Asp-Net-web-api-rest-service/ though I'm pretty agnostic about the back end, it can be any server side architecture that does the same thing (elixir, ruby, node, go, etc etc)

Comment: @azium. What's choking me now is authentication. If I have a Web API (not  a Web Application) backend just serving up JSON, does there exist a component/library  available that handles authentication/sessions for me.

Comment: json web tokens seem to the defacto standard for this type of auth. Better than sessions because it's stateless. Here's a tutorial maybe relevant https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/aspnet-webapi and this is the react-router official auth flow https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow

Comment: Thanks alot :) Can I ask for a recommendation for the React front end. Do I want to use webpack and Node.JS. What advice do you have form your experience?

Comment: Yes. Check out the boilerplate I posted in my first comment.